# Promedio de un conjunto de datos con diferentes años y diferentes sitios

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos como el siguiente ejemplo:

Son más de 2000 registros y lo que necesito es generar un promedio de los datos que contienen las columnas de coral y alga por año y por sitio.

Así que utilice la función:

```
tapply(set1$coral.cover,list(set1$site,set1$survey_year),mean)
```

Pero me aparece un error y no sé a qué se debe:

```
Error in tapply(set1$coral.cover, list(set1$site, set1$survey_year), mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aix, sin un ejemplo de los datos que estas evaluando hay un conjunto de posibilidades que se nos escapan en el diagnóstico. De todas formas te comento que no veo nada raro en tu ejemplo, de hecho hice una simulación para probar la sentencia y funcionó correctamente

```
set1 <- data.frame(coral.cover = sample(1:100, 100, replace=TRUE), 
                   coral.column = sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE),
                   site = paste0("site ",sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)), 
                   survey_year = sample(2010:2017, 100, replace=TRUE))

str(set1)
tapply(set1$coral.cover,list(set1$site,set1$survey_year),mean)
```

La salida:

```
> str(set1)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ coral.cover : int  63 35 42 15 60 65 63 59 7 55 ...
 $ coral.column: int  2 2 3 1 1 3 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ site        : Factor w/ 5 levels "site 1","site 2",..: 5 1 5 3 1 2 2 1 4 4 ...
 $ survey_year : int  2011 2016 2014 2016 2017 2014 2012 2010 2013 2015 ...

> tapply(set1$coral.cover,list(set1$site,set1$survey_year),mean)
        2010 2011     2012     2013 2014 2015     2016 2017
site 1 52.50   14 64.50000 71.00000 60.0 64.5 42.33333 60.0
site 2 48.00   11 45.75000  4.00000 64.0 74.0 63.00000   NA
site 3 29.00   15       NA 66.20000 39.8 68.0 34.00000 61.6
site 4    NA   NA 49.00000 63.33333 24.0 47.0 35.00000 81.0
site 5 42.25   58 43.16667 38.00000 37.0 40.0 54.50000   NA
```

Por lo que te diría que revises los nombres de variables y que se correspondan con la realidad, tener en cuenta el tema "CASE Sensitive"